# Pagination in Laravel with groupBy having function for custom column

Tags: php, pagination, group-by, laravel-5

My code is:

```
$jobs = \App\Job::all()
    ->groupBy(function($item) {
        return $item->created_at->format('M-Y');
    })->paginate(10);
```

and I am getting the following error :

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate();

Answer (score 1):

Thus Test:

```
$jobs = \App\Job::groupBy(function($item) {
    return $item->created_at->format('M-Y');
})->paginate(10);
```

Comment: It is not working .i get following error..
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given